# How do you check if a text file had tab as its delimiter in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

So I have a text file and it may have a tab as its field separator (delimiter) or it may have a space as a field separator. I would like to check if that text file is tabulated otherwise I will do something else with the file. I am using a bash script. So i'm open to anything with pure bash, sed, awk, grep, etc. (NOTE: that they are all GNU). So I am thinking of a structure like this:

```
if [if delimiter is tab]; then
    #do soemthing
elif [if delimiter is space]; then
    #do something else
fi
```

Any suggestions? Let me know if further explanation is required. Thanks!

Here is an explanation **update** on what the text file looks like:

If the text file has a tab as delimiter, then it delimited on every line. If the text file has a space as delimiter, then it is NOT delimited every line.

Here are examples of possible text files that I might be facing:

*Delimiter is tab*:

```
col1   col2   col3
-------
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

*Delimiter is space*: (the space is between 12 and 3 && 4 and 56)

```
col1col2col3
-----------
12 3
4 56
```

Comment: Are the files delimited on every line? (Can you guarantee that the firs t line will be delimited?) Do space delimited files have any tabs in them at all? Do tab delimited files have spaces in them at all?

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for taking interest. If the text file has a tab as delimiter, then it delimited on every line. If the text file has a space as delimiter, then it is NOT delimited every line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming a tab will only exist on the first line when the file is tab delimited then this

```
if awk '{exit !/\t/}' "$file"; then
    : # tab file
else
    : # space file
fi
```

should do what you want.

Also:

```
if [ -n "$(sed -n '/\t/p;q' "$file")" ]; then
    : # tab file
else
    : # space file
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! +1.  but I'm getting `syntax error: unexpected end of file`. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: @Alias With what code exactly? You need some non-comment contents in each block of the `if` so what I wrote isn't legal as-is. Editing to fix that.

Comment: I'm getting an error in the `if` statement for both code segments you  posted. I had `echo` statements instead of comments as well inside the `if` statements

Comment: Can you pastebin the code you have? Both of my snippets work when pasted into bash here. What shell are you using?

Comment: not sure how to check the version of shell. so i used `ps -p $$` and got: `PID TTY    TIME CMD               5270 pts/0    00:00:00 bash`

Comment: Does the file have DOS line endings? Does running `do2sunix` on it fix the problem?

Comment: Thanks!!! there were special characters since the file was created using Windows.

Comment: FWIW `awk '{exit !/\t/}' file` would do the job.

Comment: @EdMorton I thought that might be possible but wasn't sure and, for some reason, didn't test it.

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions only check that there are tabs somewhere, not that the file is correctly formatted, i.e. that each line has 3 tab-separated columns.

I'd use something like the following, which checks that each line has the correct number of tabs:

```
no_cols=3
no_lines=$(cat "${file}" | wc -l)
no_tab_lines=$(cat "${file}" | cut -f${no_cols} | sed '/^$/d' | wc -l)
if [[ ${no_lines} -eq ${no_tab_lines} ]]; then
    echo "tabs"
else
    echo "not all tabs"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is enough to test whether we have a tab on the first line, I would go without calling **awk**:

```
if `head -1 $file | grep -q '   '`; then
    : # tab file
else
    : # space file
fi
```

where the "spaces" between the two single quotes are made with Ctrl-V followed by hitting the tab key.